# How do you hydrate a store using react_on_rails' Redux API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, reactjs, redux, react-on-rails

Currently, I'm working with this setup (simplified for readability):

### react_on_rails 11.1.4

#### Layout Controller (index method):

```
redux_store('appStore', props: { foo: 'bar' })
```

#### Layout:

```
<%= redux_store_hydration_data %> (before close of body tag)
```

#### View:

```
<%= react_component('FooBar') %>
```

#### Component (FooBar):

```
ReactOnRails.getStore('appStore');
```

#### JavaScript (main.js):

```
ReactOnRails.registerStore({ appStore });
```

If I inspect the source, the data and the component appear to be present:

```
<div id="FooBar-react-component-fb8d03cb-b3d3-4247-8b4b-3e5a2ad52f84"></div>
<script type="application/json" class="js-react-on-rails-component" data-component-name="FooBar" data-trace="true" data-dom-id="FooBar-react-component-fb8d03cb-b3d3-4247-8b4b-3e5a2ad52f84">{}</script>
<script src="/main.js"></script>
<script type="application/json" data-js-react-on-rails-store="appStore">{"foo":"bar"}</script>
```

However, the component itself isn't rendering due to these fatal errors:

```
Uncaught Error: There are no stores hydrated and you are requesting the store appStore...`
Uncaught Error: Could not find store registered with name 'appStore'. Registered store names include...
```

So far as I can tell, the setup is inline with what's been outlined in the documentation, so I'm wondering if this is a bug of some sort. I've tried putting the call to `redux_store` in both the controller and the view, moving the other calls into other files and locations, etc. to no avail.

Any help is much appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem. This is how I solved it. Initially, I had this

```
const appStore = ReactOnRails.getStore("myStore");

const HelloWorldApp = (appStore) => (
    <Provider store={appStore}>
        <HelloWorldContainer />
     </Provider>
);

export default HelloWorldApp;
```

But it was failing to register the store here

```
const appStore = ReactOnRails.getStore("myStore");
```

So I changed it to this

```
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import HelloWorldContainer from './HelloWorldContainer';

const HelloWorldApp = (props) => (
    <Provider store={ReactOnRails.getStore("myStore")}>
        <HelloWorldContainer />
    </Provider>
);

export default HelloWorldApp;
```

The "There are no stores hydrated" thing is a bit misleading. A "hydrated" store, is just a populated object. When you viewed your html you did have a hydrated store it just wasn't found by the JS. I believe by adding ReactOnRails.getStore in here

```
<Provider store={ReactOnRails.getStore("myStore")}>
```

helps with the load order. I believe the reason it wasn't initially working for me is because of the JS load order. I hope this helps someone.